# How to get 2 JPanels within 1 JPanel, resizable, with fixed proportion?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

Let's say a `JFrame` contains just 1 `JPanel`. This `JPanel` is divided into 2 `JPanel`s occupying accordingly `0.75` and `0.25` of the `JFrame` height. I want all of this to be resizable along with the window size.

I have no idea how to do this in Java.

I'm a newbie to Java. I've read a bit about layouts, but all I can see is how to set preferred size in constructor (ceasing to resize when this number is reached) or some fixed sizes obtained through setting borders.

Comment: `JFrame` with `BorderLayout`, `JPanel` in frame with a `GridBagLayout`.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JFrame` with a `BorderLayout`, onto that, add a `JPanel` with a `GridBagLayout`.  Add your other two panels onto this.

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

[image: Resizable]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 0.75;

            JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            top.add(new JLabel("Top"));
            top.setBackground(Color.RED);
            add(top, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weighty = 0.25;

            JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            bottom.add(new JLabel("Bottom"));
            bottom.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            add(bottom, gbc);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```